# How do I change the colors of a Gedit theme?

Tags: 12.10, gedit

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm using a custom theme called **Twilight** for Gedit and I'm trying to change some of the colors of the theme.

I went to: `/home/user/.local/share/gedit/twilight.xml`

The default color I'm trying to change is:

```
<color name="steelblue3" value="#4f94cd"/>
```

to

```
<color name="moon_grey" value="#f7f7f7">
```

The code I'm changing:

```
<style name="bracket-match" background="steelblue3"/>
```

To this:

```
<style name="bracket-match" background="moon_grey"/>
```

But after I do use the line above, nothing happens. It still comes out as steel blue. I exited out completely and came back in and it was still the same color. I also tried "reseting" but repicking the theme in the Preferences > Fonts & Colors but nothing happened again. I also deleted the steel blue line but even than it stayed as is.

What's going on? How do I change a color of the theme?

**UPDATE**

I restarted the computer and things have changed. I have 2 files now - the regular `twilight.xml` and another `twilight.xml~` file. I cannot open `twilight.xml~` as it gives me the error:

```
Could not display "/home/user/.local/share/gedit/styles/twilight.xml~".
```

But I can click on the regular file. My changes are still there but it switched to a different theme and the Twilight theme is unavailable in the preferences. What happened to it?

Comment: Can you reopen the files and check whether your edit was saved? Can you pick another color theme and then switch back to the one you edited?

Comment: @Private OK, I gave you an update when I tried both of the things you said.

Comment: Can you run the command `ls -al` in the directory in which you find `twilight.xml` and give use the first eight characters (the permissions) of the line of `twilight.xml` and the same with the `~` version. This looks like a permissions issue.

Comment: Your `twilight.xml~`is just a temp file. You can safely delete it. There have been [several suggestions](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/17749/) on what to do about these files.

Comment: Why don't you get the source of your original theme, make a copy of it (with a different name), change/tweak whatever you want and install it. Perhaps it would let you focus on how to craft your new theme instead of worrying on possible breaks or damages to what's already installed and working fine.

Comment: @carnendil Good idea, guess I'll keep this question here though and come back to it later when I solve it.

Comment: "I cannot open twilight.xml~" this is a backup of your file `twilight.xml`. You can copy it back over the original to undo the last saved changes.

Answer (score 1):

You made some small mistakes:

```
<color name="moon_grey" value="#f7f7f7">
```

On this line, you missed the closing `/`

And you should not overwrite the `steelblue3`-definition, but just add the correct line, because steelblue is needed at other places as well.

```
<color name="moon_grey" value="#f7f7f7"/>
```

Basically, that’s it, now your brackets should be better viewable.

P.S. Posting [this link](https://raw.github.com/mig/gedit-themes/master/twilight.xml) to the source of the Twilight-Theme would have been helpful.